# Set int value in conditional statement after declaring string

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a string (`breakmsg`) that I would like to be the same for every `if` statement, with an integer `value` that needs to change depending on what it is declared as inside the `if` statement. How would I go about changing the value of the `value` variable after I have already declared the `breakmsg` string? Previous attempts are commented inside the code.

Here is my current code:

```
private int value;

    public void setValue(int v){
        value = v;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {
        Block b = e.getBlock();
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        //int value = 0;
        String breakmsg = ChatColor.GREEN + "You gained " + ChatColor.GOLD + value + ChatColor.GREEN + " points for collecting " + ChatColor.AQUA + b.getType() + ChatColor.GREEN + ".";

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int itemID = p.getItemInHand().getTypeId();

        if (b.getType() == Material.DIAMOND_ORE) {
            if (itemID == 257 || itemID == 278) {
                //value = 5;
                setValue(5);
                int points = getConfig().getInt("players." + p.getUniqueId() + ".points");
                getConfig().set("players." + p.getUniqueId() + ".points", points + value);
                saveConfig();
                startScoreboard();
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(breakmsg);
            }
        }

        if (b.getType() == Material.GOLD_ORE) {
            if (itemID == 257 || itemID == 285 || itemID == 278) {
                //value = 3;
                setValue(3);
                int points = getConfig().getInt("players." + p.getUniqueId() + ".points");
                getConfig().set("players." + p.getUniqueId() + ".points", points + value);
                saveConfig();
                startScoreboard();
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(breakmsg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the break message after all the if statements, do you want the string to be different for each value or just one string ?

Comment: PS , take a look at `StringBuilder` or `String.format()` method to prevent concatination

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap that logic in a private function.

```
private String generateBreakMsgFrom(Block block, int value) {
    return ...
}
```

Then within the `if` statements rather than setting value you can do:

```
breakmsg = generateBreakMsgFrom(b, 5);
```

Please note that you could and should probably also simply set the message after the if statements, but still you want to extract the message generation logic into a private function.

I would really recommend you to read [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). Your function is very long, it is doing multiple things, it has a lot of magic numbers and quite a lot of code duplication...

EDIT: Since you declared `int value` in your function I haven't realized that it was an instance variable, therefore.

```
private String generateBreakMsgForBlock(Block block) {
    return ... //you can use value from here once properly set
}
```